# Order relation proof of power set of R [Complete Amateur]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

I'm translating this question from French to English, and my French isn't that good so sorry if i make any mistakes.

Question is :

We provide the power set $P(\mathbb R)$ with a relation $R$ defined by $ARB$ if $A\subset B$. Show that $R$ is an Order Relation, and is it total?

Now I know that an order relation has to be: Reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

But unfortunately I don't really understand what those mean either. I have a general idea but nothing concrete.

I know that since $\mathbb R\subset P(\mathbb R)$, then $P(\mathbb R)>\mathbb R$(?) and then?

I'm going to start my first college year in a month or so, so sorry if I made any mathematical horrendous errors.

If anyone can take some time from his and explain it with some better examples, I'd be truly grateful, thanks!

Comment: yes, one means Real numbers, and one means a relation, the aRb is a relation
the P(R) is the power set of the set of real numbers.

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience caused, didn't know there was the real numbers R.

Comment: First, it is not true that $\mathbb R\subset P(\mathbb R)$. It is true that $\mathbb R\in P(\mathbb R)$. That's because the members of $P(\mathbb R)$ or not members of $\mathbb R$, the are subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you don't know what reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive mean, where did you get this problem that you weren't given definitions beforehand?

Comment: Oh, so one means the elements are what are in, and one means that the whole subset is in the other set. i hope i'm not getting it wrong.

Comment: Yes, if $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,\{5,6\}\}$ then $1\in A$, but $\{1,2\}\subset A$.  And $\{5,6\}\in A$, but $6\not\in A$ and $\{5,6\}\not\subset A$.

Comment: I was actually provided with some definitions, but i didn't really understand them that well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64061/discussion-between-mario-souper-and-thomas-andrews).